# When should user be prompted for push notifications and location

Tags: notification, prompt, location-service

Location service provides access to user location.

If application has map screen, you could ask user for location service access at map screen.

If application has an event journal screen, you could ask user for push notification service access at this screen.

But, in general, when and where you should ask user for access to push notifications and location services?

Answer (score 1):

Typically the request to turn on push notifications and location services come at different stages. Common practice has been to ask the user if they want to turn on push notifications when they open the app for the first time.

Additionally, you should only prompt the user to turn on location services when they open the screen that has the map. This way they have a clear context of why and where the location services are being used.